# Puede un trigger mandar ejecutar un reporte alojado en Reporting Service?

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

Tengo una duda y no se si hay otra manera de hacerlo, tratare de explicarlo lo mas que se puede para darme a entender.

Tengo una table con una columna Status, en ella solo alamecena Abierto o Cerrado, depende de otras columnas el Status.
Quiero hacer un trigger para revisar cada ves que a la tabla le hagan un update revise la columna Status y si la columna dice cerrado que se mande ejecutar el reporte.

Si tienen algun link de donde pueda tomar informacion util, favor de indicarmelo o si han realizado algo como lo que intento me lo podrian compartir.
Gracias.

Comment: No tengo la solución completa, pero puedes crear primero una suscripción del reporte en SSRS y posteriormente agregarla a un job y luego en el trigger ejecutar el mismo ´EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @jobid´

Comment: eso pudiera funcionar, pero no quiero agregar los correos a la suscripcion ya que los correos esta en una tabla de la base de datos, lo interesante seria como pasar esos correos a una suscripcion.